# localize dynamic drop down from database using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, localization

```
This is the language select box.

<select name="lang" id="lang" browser="Indicated by the browser">
<option value="en">English</option>
<option value="fr">French</option>
<option value="ch">Chinese</option>
<option value="sp">Spain</option>`enter code here`
</select>

This is script i have written.

<script type="text/javascript">


    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        loadBundles('en');
        jQuery('#lang').change(function() {
            var selection = jQuery('#lang option:selected').val();
            loadBundles(selection != 'browser' ? selection : null);
            jQuery('#langBrowser').empty();
            if(selection == 'browser')  {                       jQuery('#langBrowser').text('('+jQuery.i18n.browserLang()+')');
            }
        });


    });

    function loadBundles(lang) {
        jQuery.i18n.properties({
            name:'Messages', 
            path:'bundle/', 
            mode:'both',
            language:lang, 
            callback: function() {
                updateExamples();
            }
        });
    }

    function updateExamples() {
        var ex1 = 'Firstname';
        var ex2 = 'Lastname';
        var ex3 = 'Youremail';
        var ex4 = 'Reenteremail';
        var ex5 = 'Newpassword';
        var ex6 = 'Dateofbirth';
        var ex7 = 'Signup';
        var ex8 = 'Itsfreeandalwayswillbe';
        var ex9 = 'Birthlabel';
        var ex10 = 'Termslabel';
        var ex11 = 'Summarylabel';
        var ex12 = 'PersonalLabel';
        var ex13 = 'Interestlabel';
        var ex14 = 'Addlabel';
        var ex15 = 'Editlabel';
        var ex16 = 'Deletelabel';
        var spreadsheet_label = 'Spreadsheetlabel';
        var invite_google_label = 'Invitegooglelabel';
        var invite_facebook_label = 'Invitefacebooklabel';
        var upload_label = 'Uploadlabel';
        var subBut='Submit';
        var dialogTitle = 'DTitle';


        jQuery("#first_name_label").text(eval(ex1));
        jQuery("#first_name_label1").text(eval(ex1));
        jQuery("#last_name_label").text(eval(ex2));
        jQuery("#last_name_label1").text(eval(ex2));
        jQuery("#email_label").text(eval(ex3));
        jQuery("#email_label1").text(eval(ex3));
        jQuery("#reenter_email_label").text(eval(ex4));
        jQuery("#new_password_label").text(eval(ex5));
        jQuery("#date_of_birth_label").text(eval(ex6));
        jQuery("#date_of_birth_label1").text(eval(ex6));
        jQuery("#sign_up").text(eval(ex7));
        jQuery("#label1").text(eval(ex8));
        jQuery("#button").val(eval(ex7));
        jQuery("#birth_label").text(eval(ex9));
        jQuery("#terms_label").text(eval(ex10));
        jQuery("#summary_label").text(eval(ex11));
        jQuery("#personal_label").text(eval(ex12));
        jQuery("#interest_label").text(eval(ex13));
        jQuery("#add_label").text(eval(ex14));
        jQuery("#edit_label").text(eval(ex15));
        jQuery("#delete_label").text(eval(ex16));

        jQuery("#spreadsheet_label").text(eval(spreadsheet_label));
        jQuery("#invite_google_label").text(eval(invite_google_label));
        jQuery("#invite_facebook_label").text(eval(invite_facebook_label));
        jQuery("#upload_label").val(eval(upload_label));


        jQuery("#submit_button").val(eval(subBut));
        jQuery("#ui-dialog-title-dialog").text(eval(dialogTitle));


    }
  </script>

  Everything is working fine for the labels. But in the case of dynamic drop down i     got    problem. How to localize the dynamic drop down data when the user selected the   language.
 The data in the drop down is coming from the database.



 I have a language select drop down box, after selecting one language from dropdown list am able to change the text filed names and all other text in the language that is selected.
```

At the same time i have another dropdown, in that data is generated dynamically form the database. After the user selecting the language from dropdown list i have to change the data in this drop down list also. please suggest me if u have any idea.

Thank you.

Comment: show us what have you done? we will guide you with the rest then

Comment: Do you have any requirement for specific cultures? Because I made something for localization on the client side.

Comment: <select name="lang" id="lang" browser="Indicated by the browser">
<option value="en">English</option>
<option value="fr">French</option>
<option value="ch">Chinese</option>
<option value="sp">Spain</option>
</select>

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use ajax for this issue.

You can `bind` ajax to first drop down and then fill secound dropdown by data which you get from back-end.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
<select name='lang'>
<option value='eng'>Eng</option>
<option value='french'>French</option>

</select>

<!-- below div is another div whose data changes as per the language selected -->
<div id="another_div"></div>​
```

JS:

```
$("select[name='lang']").live({
change: function(e){
    var selected_lang = $("select[name='lang'] option:selected").html();

    data = {}
    data['selected_lang'] = selected_lang;
    $.ajax({
        url: "required url",
        data: data,
        success: function(res){
           $("#another_div").text(res); // if result is a direct text sent from server
            // or
            $("#another_div").text(res.content); //if result is an object with the required content present in the key 'content'
        },
        error: function(err){
            alert("error occured");                 
        }

    });        


}
 });​
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use one of the many Cascading jQuery Dropdowns:

http://www.ryanmwright.com/2010/10/13/cascading-drop-down-in-jquery/